# Does the DBI fetchrow_array method in Perl have any max size limit?

Tags: perl, dbi

I am using the `fetchrow_array` method from the [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) module to fetch some data using Perl.

It fetches a maximum of 850,000 rows, but the actual size of data is 6.4 million rows.

What should I do?

Comment: What should you do? Do you have a problem? Is it not working for you? The `fetchrow_array` method has a limit of *one* row: you fetch them one at a time.

Comment: acutally it fetched only 850000 rows.Actual data to be returned is around 6.4 million rows

Comment: it fetched 85000 diff records not one record 850,000 times.I need to fetch 640,0000 records

Comment: @user2295715: It's not clear what you are doing. Please show your code. Are you calling `fetchrow_array` 850,000 times, and on the 850,001st call it says it has come to the end of the data?

Comment: @dan1111: `fetchrow_arrayref` does the same as `fetchrow_array`, except that it returns a reference to an array instead of a list. `fetchall_arrayref` *will* try to read the entire selection in one go.

Comment: Apart from the code, schema etc, database and library versions would be useful too.

Comment: @Borodin, oops I mentally conflated `fetchrow` with `fetchall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `fetchall_arrayref` since the `fetchrow_*` methods return 1 row at a time.

Have you checked for errors as suggested by [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchall_arrayref)?

> If an error occurs, fetchall_arrayref returns the data fetched thus far, which may be none. You should check $sth->err afterwards (or use the RaiseError attribute) to discover if the data is complete or was truncated due to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently fetchrow_array runs out of memory. I am seeing this in my application. 
Try selecting into an OUTFILE.